# Cpack create a ld.so.conf

Tags: cmake, debian, cpack

I am creating a Debian package using cpack. And installing the package at `/opt/interfaces/lib`, Since the libraries are not present at standard location, I would like to add `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/interfaceslibs.conf` file and has `/opt/interfaces/lib`.

I am not quite sure how this can be achieved using CMake's cpack. I also heard that, not to make/create this file as post installation script because they can't be delete by `apt remove package`. Unfortunately, I am missing some key words/examples to accomplish this task. Is it possible to point to some simple example or some online references ?

Thanks

Comment: Using `CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA` variable you could add to the package additional script `postrm` to run after uninstalling the package. As far as I understand, this script can be used for remove system files like ones under `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`.

Answer (score 0):

1. most likely you ought to generate this file with `configure_file()`, cuz its content depends on `${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_LIBDIR}`.
2. your `CMakeLists.txt` just needs to install the generated file into `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` directory with `install(FILES...)`.
3. CPack will include it into the `*.deb` package.
4. If your package provides any dynamic libraries, CPack gonna generate a trivial `post(inst|rm)` script (that runs `ldconfig`) or you can provide your own scripts via corresponding CPackDeb variables.